# How do I select an role option via greasemonkey/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Maybe as a start, I'm quite okayish in doing JavaScript for Photoshop but web stuff feels like being lost in the desert to me.

I would appreciate your help on this one: how can I set/select let's say the word Albania?

It's hidden in a dropdown list, that I can open/unfold via script but then I'm stuck.

The `select2-result-label-xxxx` is always different when I open the site.

```
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none country-selector select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" id="select2-drop" style="left: 995.667px; width: 569px; top: 135.05px; bottom: auto; display: block;">

    <div class="select2-search">       
    <label for="s2id_autogen1_search" class="select2-offscreen"></label>       
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-3315"> </div>   

    <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-1">
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-3311" role="option">Afghanistan</div></li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-3312" role="option">Albania</div></li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-3313" role="option">Algeria</div></li>
```

Since there is the question what I already got:

All I tried went to nothing as I have no clue how to tackle this.

What I got so far is how to extract the string I need, open the popup and the dropdown.

```
//Dropdown 
window.openDropdown = function (str) {
    var dropdown = document.querySelector('.form-group div a');
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
}

//Wait Funktion
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}


var country = document.querySelector('.flexible-content p +img + p').innerHTML . split('_')[2].split('.')[0]; alert (country);

ov_link_country = document.querySelector('.flexible-content p  +img + p +p +p +p +p a');
ov_link_country.click();

sleep(500);
openDropdown(0);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please show us the code you already have?

Comment: `createEvent` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent); just use `var evt = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {...});`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent

Comment: alright, thanks for that. I'll try to implement that.
Any help or link regarding this (for me) tricky selection issue ?